# Irrational and transcendental numbers of the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)^\alpha}{s_n}$: proof verification and examples

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, reference-request, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

We denote for an integer $n>1$ its square-free kernel as $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p,\tag{1}$$
with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$. You can see this definition and the corresponding properties of this arithmetic function for example from [this Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)

I'm trying to create irrational and transcendental numbers using infinite series and this arithmetic function $(1)$.

> **Question 1.** I've written a proof for the first one, that is a proof of the statement that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{2^{2^n}}$ is a transcendental number. Is my *Proof*  below right? **Many thanks.**

**Claim.** The real number
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{2^{2^n}}$$
is a transcendental number.

*Proof.* We will need in our proof to use the (obvious) inequality $\operatorname{rad}(n)\leq n$, and the following inequalitites that can be proven by mathematical induction: $\forall n\geq 1$ one has $n\leq 2^n$, and also $\forall n\geq 1$ the inequality $2^n-n\geq 2^{n-1}$ holds.

Let $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{rad}(n)2^{-2^n}$ and we denote $x_m=\sum_{n=1}^m \operatorname{rad}(n)2^{-2^n}$. Then $x_m$ is rational with denominator $2^{2^m}$. Since for any positive integer $k$,  $$|x - x_m| \le 2 \cdot \frac{2^m}{2^{2^{m+1}}} < \left(2^{2^{m-1}}\right)^{-k}$$
for sufficiently large $m$, $x$ is a Liouville number and therefore is transcendental by Liouville's theorem.$\square$

On the other hand I would like to know a different and simple example of an irrational number represented as a series involving this arithmetic function (I know that if my proof is right *trancendental number*$\implies$ *irrational number*). I mean series of the kind $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)^\alpha}{s_n},\tag{2}$$
and here $0<\alpha$ is a fixed rational/integer number and $s_n\geq 1$ is the sequence of positive integers that you need to create yourself example.

> **Question 2.** Can you provide me an example of the type $(2)$ showing that it is an irrational number? If you know such example from the literature please refer it, answering this question as a reference request and I search and read such statement from the literature. **Many thanks.**

Comment: I've used in my example the fixed $\alpha=1$ in **Question 1**, thus I prefer in the answer for **Question 2** some example for a different $\alpha$, that is with $\alpha\neq 1$ if it is feasible.

Comment: For the second part it seems that $s_n=2^{2^n}$ should also produce a Liouville number, even if we replace the numerator in each term with $n^{\alpha}$.

Comment: Then I'm sorry for my clumsiness if there exist such obvious solutions for **Question 2**. I am going to wait some days if some user can tell me if my proof (**Question 1**) is right or if it has a good mathematical content. Many thanks for your attention and help @DanielWainfleet

Comment: Your proof or Q1 seems right to me.